# What's the equivalent of Objective-C's NSData.length with Swift's Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm doing some CoreBluetooth tutorial and got to this obj-c code:

```
if (request.offset > myCharacteristic.value.length) {
   // stuff
}
```

`value` is of type `NSData`. Since my code is in Swift 3, value is of type `Data`. However, a `Data` object does not have the property `length`. Do you know what's the equivalent in Swift?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the property `count`.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779648-count

Comment: The link is dead, an updated link is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2946901-count

Answer (score 2):

Should use the property `.isEmpty`

While `.count` replaces `.length` in Swift, it is inefficient if all you want to know is does `.count == 0`.

Using `.count` will for loop through the entire collection, whereas '.isEmpty' will stop after one.

Also '.isEmpty' returns a Bool which is easier to read and understand...

`if data.count == 0 {`

vs

`if data.isEmpty {`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780284-isempty